# data-source-for-selected-admin-ui-form

Tags: magento2, admin, ui-form

[image]

field

```
<field name="category_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Blog\Model\Config\Source\CategoryTree</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category_id</item> 
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vender_Blog/js/components/new-category</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="index=create_category:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

and new-category.js code is

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select\'], function (Select){
'use strict';
return Select.extend({

    /**
     * Normalize option object.
     *
     * @param {Object} data - Option object.
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    parseData: function (data) {
        return {
            'is_active': data.model['is_active'],
            value: data.model['category_id'],
            label: data.model['category_title']
        };
    }
});});
```

dataprovider for posts is

```
<?php 

namespace Vender\Blog\Model\Post
use Vender\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $collection;


    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $blockCollectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $blogCollectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $blogCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);

    }

    /**
     * Prepares Meta
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
public function getData()
   {


      $baseurl =  $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

       if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
           return $this->loadedData;
       }
       $items = $this->collection->getItems();
       /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
       foreach ($items as $block) {
           $temp = $block->getData();
           if ($temp['featured_img']) :
               $img = [];
           $img[0]['image'] = $temp['featured_img'];
           $img[0]['url'] = $baseurl.$temp['featured_img'];
           $temp['featured_img'] = $img;
           endif;
           $this->loadedData[$block->getId()] = $block->getData();
       }

       $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('blog');
       if (!empty($data)) {
           $block = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
           $block->setData($data);
           $this->loadedData[$block->getId()] = $block->getData();
           $this->dataPersistor->clear('blog');
       } else {
           if ($items) :
               if ($block->getData('featured_img') != null) {
                   $t2[$block->getId()] = $temp;

                   return $t2;
               } else {
                   return $this->loadedData;
               }
           endif;
       }

       return $this->loadedData;
   }

}
```

dataprovider is showing all other post details except the selected categories,so what is the solution now

Comment: Try this :
set selected valuyes in `value: [12,10],` 
`parseData: function (data) {
        return {
            'is_active': data.model['is_active'],
            options: data.model['category_id'],
            value: [12,10],
            label: data.model['category_title']
        };
    }`

Comment: Thanks for reply,problem solved ,got idea from this and i make relation of post  table collection with  category table using inner join ( 3 tables ) and Hence provided the required field in DataProvider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i make custom join and provided the required fields in the Dataprovider

> $id = $block->getPost_id();
>       $selectedCategories=$this->resourcePost->getCatData($id);
>        foreach ($selectedCategories as $key => $value) 
>         $this->loadedData[$id]['category_id'][$key]  = $value['category_id'];

And the function in

> ```
>  public function getCatData($id )//get data for selected category w.s.t post and merge it in dataprovider of post
>  {
>     $categoryArr=[];
>    $sql="SELECT category.category_id FROM pme_blog_post 
>         as post INNER JOIN vendor_blog_post_category as post_category 
>                     ON post.post_id = post_category.post_id 
>                 INNER JOIN vendor_blog_category as category 
>                     ON post_category.category_id = category.category_id WHERE post.post_id IN ($id)";
> ```

```
           $arrays= $this->getConnection()->query($sql);
           foreach ($arrays as $key => $val)
                {
                    $categoryArr[$key]['category_id'] = $val['category_id']; }
            return $categoryArr; 
 }
```

Comment: if need help related to this issue,  feel free to ask for help